# In python, why does 0xbin() return False?

Tags: python

Inputting the command `0xbin()` returns False:

```
>>> 0xbin()
False
```

Why does that happen? This syntax should have no meaning whatsoever. Functions cannot start with 0, there are no "i" and "n" in hex, and the bin function must have some arguments.

2023 update: [this is soon expected to be a syntax error](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/87999).

Comment: It takes arguments! `0xbin(013,37)`

Comment: @nneonneo and if you want to get `True` you can try `0xbin(11,)` with a single argument

Comment: `0xbin(013,37)` will also give you True ;) (in Python 2.7)

Comment: This is simply because the implementor of the lexer and parser is only concerned with obtaining the desired behaviors over nicely formatted code. The juxtaposition of `0xb` and `in` should be treated as an invalid token.

Comment: Compare and contrast with `0xband()`.  [Tokenizer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tokenize.html) is greedy and takes 0xba as a token.

Comment: @people who are voting to reopen: Please explain why this is not a dupe.  If you convince me, I'll dupehammer reopen it.

Comment: @Kevin Maybe the dupe target is like "Why isn't whitespace required sometimes between tokens?" and this question is like "What even are the tokens?" (I could re-open myself, but since I answered and there were many votes I won't, in case it is viewed as a COI)

Answer (score 231, accepted):

Python seems to interpret `0xbin()` as `0xb in ()`, meaning is eleven in an empty tuple.
The answer is no, therefore `False`.

Comment: So apparently "in", "is" etc don't require spaces? First time I encountered this, but it makes sense as "<" and "==" don't require them as well.

Comment: Apparently yes. The [Python Reference](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#whitespace-between-tokens) says whitespace between tokens is only needed "if their concatenation could be interpreted as a different token". But I have only ever seen such code in [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @MattS This is why valid python identifiers (and many other languages) only accept alpha or underscore for the first letter of the identifier then allow numeric afterwards. The actual implementation is fairly complicated because of full Unicode support, but the pure ASCII regex for an identifier would be: `r'[_a-zA-Z][_a-zA-Z0-9]*'`

Comment: @Aaron: `[_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*` in regular expression languages that allow (Unicode) characters classes, i. e. not Python’s. ;-]

Comment: Wow, I thought this kind of parsing was only done in Fortran and BASIC. I can't believe a modern language does it.

Comment: One of the reasons for the peculiar definition of a "preprocessing number" in the C language family is to prevent things like this; in those languages `0xbin` would be treated as a single token, even though it cannot be interpreted as a valid numeric literal.

Comment: @DavidFoerster You can just use [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) instead of the built-in `re`. It provides the same API but adds a lot of features, including matching unicode properties etc. I hope that in a few releases that will replace the standard `re` module... (and I believe the author has this hope too, hence the high level of compatibility between the two).

Comment: @Barmar python is pretty old.

Comment: @RonJohn I've been programming for 40 years, Python is less than 30 years old. As far as I'm concerned, it's a young whipper-snapper.

Comment: @Barmar: Python [wants to remain](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3099) an [LL(1) language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_grammar).  That doesn't really have anything to do with this example in particular, but it illustrates their ongoing desire for a "dumb" parser (and also provides a little in the way of explanation.  TL;DR: They don't want Python to end up like Perl.).

Answer (score 143):

If you disassemble the code, you'll see that [Yself's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51521235/6260170), which mentions that `0xbin()` is interpreted as `0xb in ()`, is confirmed:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis('0xbin()')
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (11)
              2 BUILD_TUPLE              0
              4 COMPARE_OP               6 (in)
              6 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: `list(tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(b"0xbin()").readline))` might be more appropriate

Answer (score 64):

You can use Python's own tokenizer to check!

```
import tokenize
import io
line = b'0xbin()'
print(' '.join(token.string for token in tokenize.tokenize(io.BytesIO(line).readline) if token.type!=59))
```

This prints the tokens in your string, separated by spaces. In this case, the result will be:

```
0xb in ( )
```

In other words, it returns False because the number 11 (`0xb`) is not in the empty tuple (`()`).

(Thanks to Roman Odaisky for suggesting the use of `tokenize` in the comments!)

EDIT: To explain the code a bit more thoroughly: the `tokenize` function expects input in a bit of a weird format, so `io.BytesIO(line).readline` is a function that turns a sequence of bytes into something `tokenize` can read. `tokenize` then tokenizes it and returns a series of `namedtuple`s; we take the string representing each one and join them together with spaces. The `type != 59` part is used to ignore the encoding specifier that would otherwise show up at the beginning.

Comment: This is the best answer yet, the "dis" and "ast" answers obscure what is going on behind uncommon notations, this shows it clearly in normal python.

Answer (score 54):

You can use the [AST](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) module to get the [abstract syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree) of the expression:

```
>>> import ast
>>> m = ast.parse('0xbin()')
>>> ast.dump(m)
'Module(
    body=[Expr(
               value=Compare(left=Num(n=11),
                             ops=[In()],
                             comparators=[Tuple(elts=[],
                                                ctx=Load())
                                         ]
                            ))])'
```

See the [abstract grammar](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#abstract-grammar) for how to interpret the expression, but tl;dr: `Num(n=11)` is the `0xb` part, and `Tuple(elts=[], ...)` hints towards an empty tuple rather than a function call.